# Hash Table Size

Tags: c++, hash, segmentation-fault

I have a simple question about the size of hash tables relative to the amount of data you're working with.

I'm working on a project that needs to process the entirety of the book war and peace, storing each unique word and using a "count" field to keep track of duplicates. The book, when downloaded in plain text from the Gutenberg Project is 3152KB in size (that's a HUGE plain text doc).

I was getting weird seg-fault errors when attempting to hash various test-files and couldn't seem to find any common thread except that Large files with massive amounts of unique words seemed to all cause the program to throw a seg-fault. This pointed to collision error's being the issue.

I'm using linked list "buckets" to take care of collision, and the following hash algorithm:

```
unsigned int Hash(const std::string& str)
{
   unsigned int hash = 5381;

   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
      hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + str[i]) % HashT::tableSize;
   }

   return hash;
}
```

I managed to resolve the seg-faults by increasing the `tableSize` (which is the number of elements the `hashTableArray` gets initialized with), and after that everything worked fine. The thing that has me kind of concerned is that I had to make `tableSize = 10000000` (ten million) before it would work.

My question then, is if that is way more memory that I should need given that hash function and collision resolution technique? Is the fact that I needed to make it that big a sign that something is wrong somewhere along the chain? I don't have enough experience with hash tables to have a gut feeling as to whether that's reasonable or not.

Here's my addItem function if it helps:

```
void Hash::addItem(string key)
{
    int index = hash(key);

    if (HashTable[index] == nullptr) {
        HashTable[index] = new item;
        HashTable[index]->key = key;
        HashTable[index]->count = 1;
    }
    else {
        item *temp = HashTable[index];
        item *newP = new item;

        while (temp->next != nullptr && temp->key != key)
            temp = temp->next;

        if (temp->key == key) {
            temp->count++;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = newP;
            newP->key = key;
            newP->count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I can post the header and implementation files if you want.

Comment: Are you using chaining? Like, you have an array of buckets, each bucket is a linked list? If so the size shouldn't matter at all for insertion... and only performance on lookups.

Comment: Implementation note: your hash function should either return a hash by itself, or take the size as an argument.

Comment: I am using chaining, which is why I was kind of uncomfortable with the seg-faults going away when I increased tableSize.

And I'm not sure what you mean in your implementation note. It should take in the tableSize as a parameter? It's a private data member of the class, so wouldn't that be unnecessary?

Comment: Does your `item` `class`/`struct` have a default constructor setting `next` to `nullptr`?  Because `addItem()` isn't doing that when creating a new `HashTable` entry....  Separately, you have `item *newP = new item;` run before working out if `key` is already in the list... if so you increment `count` but leak the memory for `newP`: you should allocate the memory in your `else` scope, and also be sure to set `next` to `nullptr` there.  Your function can also accept the `string key` parameter by reference (i.e. `const std::string& key`) to avoid potential slow-but-safe copy construction.

Comment: More generally - no - you shouldn't need anything like that number of buckets.  You can get a feel for what's reasonable by using `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m; std::string word; while (std::cin >> word) ++m[word]; std::cout << m.bucket_count() << '\n';` - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_count).